Not able to get inside the for loop in React js
I am making a To-Do App. I am using React frontend, Node backend, and Postgresql DB.
I made a component called <TaskLists /> which takes three properties or props:

startDate
endDate
allTasks

allTasks is an array of task lists. Its basic structure is as follows:
allTasks = [
    {
        id: //taskList id
        list_date: //taskList date
        tasks: [
            {
                id: // task id
                title: // task title
                done: // boolean value either true or false
            }, ...
        ]
    }, ...
]

I am getting this allTasks array from my backend successfully as I can see from my react dev tool.
Using startDate and endDate, I am rendering all the task lists with their list_date b/w the two using the <TaskLists /> component.
I am trying to render today's tasks (i.e. 19-07-2024) by the following code:
<TaskLists startDate={props.currentDate} endDate={props.currentDate} currentDate={props.currentDate} allTasks={props.allTasks} />

I made the startDate and endDate property same to currentDate (i.e. 19-07-2024) which I am getting from a parent component.
Now inside my <TaskLists /> component, I want to render either the list of tasks having list_date b/w startDate and endDate or I want to render a <TaskListAbsent /> component which renders if there is no task list b/w startDate and endDate.
So I made a useState() hook:
const [requiredTaskLists, setRequiredTaskLists] = useState([]);

Following is the code to set the variable requiredTaskLists:
const changeRequiredTaskLists = () => {
    let newTaskList = [];
    for(let i=0; i<props.allTasks.length; i++) {
      if(props.startDate <= props.allTasks[i].list_date && props.endDate >= props.allTask[i].list_date) {
        newTaskList.push(allTasks[i]);
      }
    }
    setRequiredTaskLists(newTaskList);
  }

And then I called the changeRequiredTaskLists() function in a useEffect() hook to call that function with every render:
useEffect(() => {
    changeRequiredTaskLists();
}, []);

And lastly, I am rendering the <TaskLists /> component as follows:
return (
    <>
      {
        requiredTaskLists.length !== 0 ? 
        <>
          {
            requiredTaskLists.map((taskList) => {
              // code for displaying every `taskList` from `requiredTaskLists` array.
            })
          }
        </> : 
        <>
          <TaskListAbsent />
        </>
      }
    </>
  )

But the problem is that for loop inside checkRequiredTaskLists is not getting executed. And I can confirm that with console logs.
Console logs just before and after for loop are getting executed and but console logs inside for loop are not getting executed.
And therefore, the newTaskList array remains empty [] and requiredTaskLists gets set to an empty array too []. Hence, requiredTaskLists.length always equals to 0.
And hence my code for displaying list is not rendering at all. It is always the <TaskListAbsent /> component which is rendering.
Please help me with this. Tell me where I am wrong. And is there is another way to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

So props.allTasks that you pass into TaskLists, where does that come from, is it initially empty and then a useEffect somewhere populates it with data from your db? If so, that'll mean your useEffect that calls changeRequiredTaskLists will be using that initial empty allTasks array. Your main issue is that your useEffect here doesn't pass in its dependencies (which is technically the changeRequiredTaskLists function), you should be passing something like [props.allTasks, props.startDate, props.endDate] as your useEffect() dependency array.

It looks like there is a typo here props.allTask[i].list_date, should be allTasks. And additionally you useEffect should be called every time when dependencies change:


 useEffect(() => {
    changeRequiredTaskLists();
  }, [props.startDate, props.endDate, props.allTasks]);



For loop is a little bit too complex here, maybe better use filter:


  const changeRequiredTaskLists = () => {
    const newTaskList = props.allTasks.filter(taskList => {
      return props.startDate <= taskList.list_date && props.endDate >= taskList.list_date;
    });
    setRequiredTaskLists(newTaskList);
  }



Hope this will help
